# How to retrieve a Page's Story (about tab) with Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find this information anywhere, went through all fields on the [Graph API Page Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/), played around with the [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) but had no luck.

So my question is how to retrieve the Page's Story (on the about tab) from the API:

[image: location of the story information]

Comment: if it´s not there, then it´s not possible to get: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's it. There's no way to retrieve it for now.